# azure function outgoing service bus message with correlation filter

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have an azure function that I want to send a message to a service bus that has a correlation filter on it.  Specifically the correlation filter is on the label/subject with a value of 'APPLICATION'.  correlation filter

[image]

How do I send the message from the azure function so that it will set this value and the subscription will receive the message?

Currently the function is set up something like this:

index.js:

```
module.exports = async function(context, inMessage) {
  context.bindings.outMessage = someJavascriptObject;
}
```

function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "inMessage",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "some_topic_1",
      "subscriptionName": "SUBSCRIPTION_NAME",
      "connection": "CONNECTION_STRING_1"
    },
    {
      "name": "outMessage",
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "topicName": "some_topic_2",
      "connection": "CONNECTION_STRING_2",
      "direction": "out"
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported. Please see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/21884